# Can't redirect after login success in laravel 5 authentication

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have problem with my authentication in laravel 5, it works if I enter the wrong username and password and the error appear, but when success, it doesn't redirect to dashboard, and no errors appear.

here's my code 'AuthController':

```
public function login(LoginRequest $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $remember = (Input::get('remember')) ? true : false;
    if($this->auth->validate(['username' => Input::get('username'),'password' => Input::get('password'), 'active' => 1], $remember)){
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }else{
        return redirect('/login')->withErrors([
            'failed' => 'Username or Password is invalid. Please try again.',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry guys, I get it solved..
just changed $this->auth->validate to be  $this->auth->attempt and the redirect to be return redirect()->intended('dashboard');

Answer (score 0):

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    protected $redirectTo = '/';
    protected $loginPath = '/login';
}
```

Much easier....